# Не выполняется запрос в oracle

Tags: oracle

Не выполняется запрос в oracle, пишет

```
EXEC flight_select;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 11, column 47:
PL/SQL: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
ORA-06550: line 6, column 2:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 21, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FLIGHT_SELECT" when expecting one of the following:
   := . ( @ % ;
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Сам запрос:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE 
    ID_flight NUMBER;
    ID_bus NUMBER;
    ID_route NUMBER;
BEGIN 
    SELECT
        flight.ID_flight,
        flight.ID_bus,
        flight.ID_route,    
        route.route_number,
        flight.driver + ' ' + bus.regist_number AS "водитель и регистрацоный номера"
    FROM flight
    LEFT OUTER JOIN route ON route.ID_route = flight.ID_route
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bus ON bus.ID_bus = flight.ID_bus
    WHERE
        ( ID_flight IS NULL OR flight.ID_flight = ID_flight) AND
        ( ID_bus IS NULL OR flight.ID_bus = ID_bus) AND
        ( ID_route IS NULL OR flight.ID_route = ID_route)
END;

EXEC flight_select;
```

Что не правильно я делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут несколько проблем. Во-первых, `EXEC` выполняет процедуру. Соответственно, вам ее надо сначала создать:

```
create or replace procedure flight_select is
    ID_flight NUMBER;
    ID_bus NUMBER;
    ID_route NUMBER;
...
end;
/
```

И так далее. Не забудьте в конце поставить `/`. Во-вторых, в процедуре нельзя просто сделать `select` - надо указать, куда поместить результаты. Например, так:

```
SELECT  flight.ID_flight,
        flight.ID_bus,
        flight.ID_route
into ID_flight, ID_bus NUMBER, ID_route
FROM flight
...
```

Количество столбцов должно в точности равняться количеству переменных (и типы должны совпадать). Запрос при этом должен возвращать ровно одну строку. Если строк будет ноль или больше одной - вы получите исключения `NO_DATA_FOUND` или `TOO_MANY_ROWS` соответственно.
Ну и последнее - у вас в коде перед `END` точка с запятой пропущена.

Comment: И еще плюс к этому в названии колонки `водитель и регистрацоный номера` 31 символ. Oracle допускает названия только из 30 байт. Причем именно байт, если кодировка сессии UTF-8 то один русский символ - это 2 байта

Comment: @Mike Точно, я и не заметил